# Why does Pytorch expect a DoubleTensor instead of a FloatTensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

From everything I see online, `FloatTensors` are Pytorch's default for everything, and when I create a tensor to pass to my generator module it is a `FloatTensor`, but when I try to run it through a linear layer it complains that it wants a `DoubleTensor`.

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Generator, self).__init__()
    self.fully_connected = nn.Linear(100, 1024*4*4, bias=False)

  def forward(self, zvec):
    print(zvec.size())
    fc = self.fully_connected(zvec)
    return(fc.size())

gen = Generator();

gen(torch.from_numpy(np.random.normal(size=100)))
```

Which produces

```
RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.DoubleTensor but found type torch.FloatTensor for argument #2 'mat2'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Problem here is that your numpy input uses `double` as data type the same data type is also applied on the resulting tensor.

The `weights` of your layer `self.fully_connected` on the other hand are `float`. When feeding data trough the layer a matrix multiplication is applied and this multiplication requires both matrices to be of same data type.

**So you have two solutions:**

- **You can convert your input to float:**

*By changing:*

```
gen(torch.from_numpy(np.random.normal(size=100)))
```

*To:*

```
gen(torch.from_numpy(np.random.normal(size=100)).float())
```

Your input which is fed into `gen` will be converted to `float` then.

*Full working code for converting inputs:*

```
from torch import nn
import torch
import numpy as np
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.fully_connected = nn.Linear(100, 1024*4*4, bias=False)

    def forward(self, zvec):
        print(zvec.size())
        fc = self.fully_connected(zvec)
        return(fc.size())

gen = Generator();
gen(torch.from_numpy(np.random.normal(size=100)).float()) # converting network input to float
```

---

- **Or alternatively you can convert your layer weights to double:**

If you need the *double precision* you can also convert your `weights` to `double`.

*Change this line:*

```
self.fully_connected = nn.Linear(100, 1024*4*4, bias=False)
```

*Just to:*

```
self.fully_connected = nn.Linear(100, 1024*4*4, bias=False).double()
```

*Full working code for converting weights:*

```
from torch import nn
import torch
import numpy as np
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.fully_connected = nn.Linear(100, 1024*4*4, bias=False).double() # converting layer weights to double()

    def forward(self, zvec):
        print(zvec.size())
        fc = self.fully_connected(zvec)
        return(fc.size())

gen = Generator();
gen(torch.from_numpy(np.random.normal(size=100)))
```

---

So both ways should work for you, but if you don't need the extra precision of `double` you should go with `float` as `double` requires more computational power.

Comment: thanks. I had a similar problem and your explanation solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy returns a 64 bit floating point number, which is cast to `DoubleTensor` when `.from_numpy()` is called. The confusing part is, if you run `print(type(zvec))` it returns `torch.Tensor` whether or not it is a float or a double.